# How does linux kernel do regression test?

Tags: testing, linux-kernel, regression-testing

I am very curious about how the Linux kernel does regression testing. I know there are existed test suites like LTP, kselftests to ensure the quality of linux kernel. And there are also regzbots to track the linux kernel regressions. But it seems there are no official projects to do continues integration for linux kernel. I have found a project called kernelCI, and it maintains lots of regression reports. However, only several test cases from LTP and kselftests are included in the regression process.

In my opinion, the regression process need to test all available test cases, at least all unit test cases, but I can not find where it is happened for linux kernel.

For a regression process, two components are essential, one is test suite, and another is a system like jenkins. Such two components are both available (LTP, kselftest for test suite, jenkins, kernelci for system), but I can not find a public source of regression test process for linux kernel.

Comment: `like LTP, kselftest` `kernelCI` so you found them, so what more do you need? `For a regression process, two components are essential, one is test suite, and another is a system like jenkins` ? Why do you need jenkins? Just run a shell script. Regression test is a _type_ of test that just tests existing behavior. Jenkins is not essential to regression tests, or any other tests.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks for your comments. Yes, I have got the test cases, so my question is where are these test cases applied? For general softwares, they use jenkins to do CI for sub-stream tasks like build and unit tests, and such data can be found publicly. However, I can not find such data of linux kernel. Are these regression process of kernel all closed source?

Comment: `For general softwares, they use jenkins` No, _some_ companies use jenkins. Some use travis, gitlab-cicd, github-cicd, screwdriver, bitbucket-pipelines. Azure, CircleCI. And some use custom scripts. I get the impression you think it is, Jenkins is nowhere universal (and I do not like jenkins, because groovy). `such data can be found publicly` Also no, many companies have jenkins (and gitlab and bitbucket and...) installed on premise.

Answer (score 2):

There are several CI systems for Linux kernel testing: KernelCI, CKI, 0-day, syzbot, LKFT. The results would be aggregated into KCIDB. You'd better have a look of the Kernel Testing materials (video or pdf) of Linux Plumbers Conferences (https://lpc.events/event/17/sessions/157/#20231113) if interested in the testing infrastructure.

These links might help:

1. https://qa-reports.linaro.org/lkft/
2. https://syzkaller.appspot.com/upstream/
3. https://lore.kernel.org/oe-lkp/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually, I have got the data from KCIDB before 2023-11. After analysing, I found there are only part of common test cases are used for kernel in common CI process (only about 30% test cases from LTP and kselftests are involved in the CI process). Thus it confuses me what test cases are used for the common CI process (other than LTP or kselftests). 
I have seen part of the result of LKFT from KCIDB, but it seems a little different from it's website. I will check it out. 
LKP is a new source for me, thank you for providing that.